# How to find Expectation of a Random Variable √X in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distribution

> How to calculate Expected Value of Random Variable  √X

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case of Discrete Random Variable:

- E[x]=  Σ (x) * P(x)
- E[√X]= Σ (√x) * P(x)

---

In case of Continuous Random Variable:

- E[x]=   ∫ (x) * f(x) dx
- E[√X]=  ∫ (√x) * f(x) dx

Integrate on all values of X